# Is it possible to retrieve video decoder output in Flash?

Tags: actionscript, streaming

Assuming I use OMSF, FlowPlayer or FWPlayer (all of these are open source), do you know if it is possible to retrieve the output from the decoder (a streaming stream) so that I can detect image freezes, artifacts, get bitrate, current level etc ... ?

Thank you !